# "Ich schweig Deinen Namen" - Kann schweigen transitiv sein?

Tags: word-usage

Aus Tokio Hotels Lied 'Spring Nicht':

> Ich schweig Deinen Namen, weil Du ihn jetzt nicht hören willst.

Soviel ich weiß, kann man nicht 'etwas schweigen', weil 'schweigen' intransitiv ist. ([Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schweigen))

Kann man 'etwas schweigen' sagen? Bedeutet es 'etwas nicht sagen'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist richtig: *Schweigen* ist intransitiv, deshalb: "Ich schweige".

Aber es gibt auch die transitive Variante (wie übrigens bei vielen Verben) *etw. verschweigen*. Zum Beispiel:

> Er hat das verschwiegen.

Comment: Vielleicht noch einen Satz zur künstlerischen Freiheit, die hier absichtlich die Regeln verletzt...

Comment: Exactly: poetic licence at work here.

Comment: Ein Fall von "Reim dich oder ich fress dir!"? Oder eine Metapher; "den Namen schweigen" kann man anders deuten als "nicht sagen" oder gar "verschweigen" (was mit "geheimhalten" konnotiert ist).